# Ruboto barcode tutorial, build fails

Tags: android, ruby, jruby, zxing, ruboto

going through the tutorial of the ruboto barcode scanner and i have ran into a problem that i can not figure out.

first of all, the tutorial is here https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Tutorial%3A-barcode-scanning#add-the-zxinglib-utility-project

here is my repository https://github.com/alucero270/ruboto_barcode_scanner-

i completed all the steps given by the tutorial, but i dont quite understand what is being asked to do in this statement:

> Copy the android-zxinglib-1.0/ZXingLib directory besides your project.

other than that, everything else is done according

when i run rake install start:

> ```
> BUILD FAILED /home/alex/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:577: ../ZXingLib resolve to a path with no project.properties file for
> ```
>
> project /home/alex/Ruby/ruboto/barcode_scanning
>
> Total time: 0 seconds rake aborted! Command failed with status (1):
>   [ant debug...]

any help will be greatly appreciated and thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 0):

In the previous step ( https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Tutorial%3A-barcode-scanning#add-the-zxing-core-jar-to-your-project ) you are asked to download a ZIP file.  Inside that ZIP file there is a directory called "android-zxinglib-1.0/ZXingLib".  You should extract that directory and place it in the same directory your project directory is located, so they are located side-by-side.

The "ZXingLib" directory is referenced from your project by the path "../ZXingLib", so make sure it is placed correctly.